# How to configure networking on an appliance such that it can plug and play on any corporate network?

Tags: windows, networking

I had a chance to configure a Moxa NPort device server appliance on my client's network, it was very easy to do so, done in just 2 minutes.

Here's what I did:-

1. The Moxa device server had a preset IP address of 192.168.127.254 and subnet mask 255.255.255.0 - http://www.moxa.com/doc/manual/nport/5400/NPort_5400_Series_Users_Manual_v4.pdf
2. Moxa provides a Windows software which I used to "scan" for the device server. It worked like magic! The software returns a list of device servers found.  Each device server is identified by MAC address, and by selecting the device server using the software, I can reset the default IP address and subnet mask of that device server!

**EDIT:** I ran the "scan" against Wireshark and it returned -

> 48    2.376493    192.168.0.3 255.255.255.255 UDP Source port: 63281  Destination port: iims

In comparison, during an earlier project, I spent 2 hours trying to get KVM to work for a Windows 7 embedded appliance I'm trying to install in my client's network - https://superuser.com/questions/380305/how-to-configure-windows-7-professional-appliance-pc-on-my-clients-network-usin

Prior to that, I have already tried pre-configuring the IP address and subnet mask to the one which my client provided, yet the appliance still can't connect to the client's network!  I've also tried cross cable, didn't work either.  After KVM worked, I discovered that the network settings were "lost" after I plug the machine into the client's network.

Now my question is what can I do to setup my Windows 7 embedded appliance so that it can connect to any network like that the Moxa device server?

I tried experimenting this on my network using a Windows machine configured to an IP address of 192.168.127.254  and subnet mask 255.255.255.0, but it doesn't connect to my network that uses 192.168.0.*.  :(

**EDIT:**

I would like to point out that the Moxa Windows configuration software seems to be able to connect to any Moxa device connected to the network even if it is on a ***different subnet***, as long as the network adapter shows "connected". This is important because the Moxa device has no VGSM port or interface to configure the IP address.

Comment: Well, yeah... You might want to give this a quick read through: http://serverfault.com/questions/49765/how-does-subnetting-work

Comment: Moxa's magical scanning software is communicating at Layer 2 only; that's why devices are identified by MAC address. IP subnets are irrelevant at Layer 2.

Comment: Thanks, I know that it is using some methods but didn't know what it's called.  Will do my research on Layer 2.  I think we're getting close to an answer. :)

Comment: @Miles Erickson - By the way, I ran the "scan" against Wireshark and it returned - **48 2.376493 192.168.0.3 255.255.255.255 UDP Source port: 63281 Destination port: iims**

Answer (score 1):

I find the best way to go about this is DHCP reservations for the equipment. DHCP reservation will ensure the device gets the same IP address every time, so to the unknown user it will appear as a static address.

After making it a dhcp client, the company's IT department is fully aware of the device since it will be sitting in their dhcp pools. If the device needs replacing it's a simple rekeying of the new mac address.

Comment: thanks for your reply, really appreciate it, am disappointed with the less enthusiastic response to network novices such as myself. If I were an expert, I could Google and find my own answer, wouldn't need to ask. I've did a quick research on DHCP reservations.... to be continued.

Comment: I just realized that I am using it for my NETGEAR broadband router :)  My impression is that it is used to "fix" the IP address of the appliance only after the administrator has managed to gained access to the appliance. Here's the article I referred to - http://lifehacker.com/5822605/how-to-set-up-dhcp-reservations-so-you-never-have-to-check-an-ip-address-again